# Starting two cpu blocking listeners and wait until one of them finishes

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, telethon

I am trying simultaneously to listen for a telegram or a discord message, whatever the first comes in. For Telegram I'm using Telethon:

```
async def listentg():
    tgclient = TelegramClient('anon', conntg.tg_api_id, conntg.tg_api_hash)
    @tgclient.on(events.NewMessage(chats=conntg.canaltg, pattern=patternmatch))
    async def tg_event_handler(event):
        print("Telegram message listened")
        await tgclient.disconnect()
    await tgclient.start()
    await tgclient.run_until_disconnected()
```

And for Discord I'm using Discum

```
async def listendc():
    dcclient = discum.Client(token=conndc.tokendc, log=False)
    @dcclient.gateway.command
    def dc_event_handler(resp):
        if resp.event.message:
            print("Discord message listened")
            dcclient.gateway.close()
    dcclient.gateway.run()
```

I understand that for running simultaneously CPU blocking code i have to (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) [use python processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor), but I don't know how to do this, just wait for the first one to return the value.

Comment: If `discum` blocks the entire thread, then yes, you need `loop.run_in_executor`. It should be enough to make your `def listendc` non-async and use `run_in_executor`; what problems did you face with this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to have them in parallel for simultaneously, it is easier to have them concurrent (but still simultaneosly waiting). You can use [Python Thread-based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) instead.